# Deserializer in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

> Given a serialized hash of any depth in string format, convert it into a hash object.

I want to know if my approach is correct, I am capturing states and storing the results in a stack and generating the hash from the stack. Also, is there a name for this kind of parsing approach?

```
def deserialize(input)
  h = {}
  l = 0
  stack = []
  curr_string = ""
  while l < input.length do
    case input[l]
    when "{" #state = DICT_START
      curr_string = ""
    when ":" #state =  VALUE_START
      stack.push(curr_string)
      curr_string = ""
    when "}", "," #state = DICT_END
      if curr_string != "" then
        stack.push(curr_string)
      end
      if stack.length > 0 then
        val = stack.pop
        key = stack.pop
        stack.push({key => val})
      end  
      curr_string = ""
    else
      curr_string+=input[l]
    end
    l+=1
  end
  stack.each {|n| h.merge!(n)}
  h
end

p deserialize("{a:test,b:test1,c:test3}")
p deserialize("{a:{b:test1}}")
p deserialize("{a:{b:{c:test1}}}")
p deserialize("{a:{b:{c:test1}},d:123}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for this type of parsing is called the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Your code itself seems fine, as long as you don't intend to support strings with curly braces, e.g. `deserialize("{a:{b:'{{{{{{{{'}}")`.  The biggest issue I see is that it's not very ruby-like in the naming or formatting.  I've made brief attempt at cleaning it up a little below.

```
def deserialize(input)
  hash = {}                 # avoid one letter variable names
  stack = [] 
  curr_string = ''          # use single quotes for uninterpolated strings

  input.chars.each do |c|   # This is a better was to loop through the characters
    case c 
      when '{' 
        curr_string = ''
                            # whitespace makes it easier to read the different cases
      when ':' 
        stack.push(curr_string)
        curr_string = ''

      when '}', ',' 
        stack.push(curr_string) unless curr_string.empty?  # unless is the same as "if not"
                                                           # also use one line statements when the logic is simple
        if stack.length > 0
          val = stack.pop
          key = stack.pop
          stack.push({key => val})
        end  
        curr_string = ''

      else
        curr_string += c
    end
  end
  stack.each { |n| hash.merge!(n)}
  hash
end
```